# How to receive acknowledgement in JMS

Tags: java, jms, publish-subscribe

Here's my scenario. The program is developed with publisher/subscriber methodology. Have two topics (topic1, topic2) in producer and consumer part. I need to get the acknowledgement of the received topic1 from consumer in producer program so that when the acknowledgement status is true, the producer program will have to send the message on topic2.

Had googled links suggesting `session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` in consumer. But I'm in need of the Acknowledgement status to be returned to producer for further process.

Answer (score 4):

JMS specification does not define any API for a publisher to know if a message was consumed by a subscriber or not. A publisher just publishes a message and it is the messaging provider/broker to deliver that message to subscriber. A broker will deliver the message if there is a subscription otherwise that message is discarded.

The `session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` option is one of the way a consumer tells a **messaging provider (not producer)** to remove the message from it's queue/memory. There are couple of other acknowledgement options as well but all these options are for telling a messaging provider to remove the message but **not** telling a producer.

If producer requires an acknowledgement from a consumer, then consumer will have to publish an acknowledgement message on another topic and producer subscribes to that topic to receive those acknowledgements. For example:

Producer publishes on `TOPIC1`
Producer subscribes to `TOPIC1/ACKS`
Consumer subscribes to `TOPIC1`
After receiving a message
Consumer publishes an acknowledgement message to `TOPIC1/ACKS`
Producer will receive the acknowledgement message.
It can then publish on TOPIC2

You must note that there can be multiple acknowledgement messages as there can be more than one subscribers on TOPIC1.

Comment: Can you direct me towards an example?

Answer (score 0):

If your program contains only one message producer, you can create a Queue in the message consumer and let the producer subscribe to that Queue. In the Queue mode, it's point-to-point. So the message will only be delivered from the consumer to the producer.

Alternatively, you can also use [setJMSReplyTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSReplyTo%28javax.jms.Destination%29) method to specify the Queue you want the consumer reply to when it receives the message from the producer. This way you don't need to create the Queue explicitly in the consumer but you can create the Queue in the producer as well. But you still need to let the producer listen to that Queue to received the acknowledgement.